# Iterator and Memory Usage

Tags: java, mapreduce, iterator

I was reading the MapReduce paper ([MapReduce](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/us/archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf)) and came across the below statement:

> The intermediate values are supplied to the user's reduce function via
>   an iterator. This allows us to handle lists of values that are too
>   large to fit in memory.

Does this mean there's a relation between using *Iterators* and the memory usage of large lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction is that the contents backing an `Iterator` don't necessarily have to be in memory. The contents of a `List` generally are, but you could write an `Iterator<Integer>` that read a file on disk and returned the values in order.

Comment: Does this mean the _Iterator_ is designed such a way that it can read data from disk and load into memory on demand??

Comment: @srk1990 `Iterator` is an interface that specifically doesn't address how the underlying implementation gets its values. You could write a Fibonacci-sequence one that generates values on the fly.